# Subdomain Redirect Error + Htaccess, confused?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, subdomain

I noticed several weeks ago, that my whole site was being mirrored by a strange subdomain in google search.

Ex. www.site.com

Being indexed in Google:

www.site.comwww.site.com/index.html ==
www.site.com/index.html

www.site.comwww.site.com/contact ==
www.site.com/contact

etc ... the above pages are identical.

Strange thing is any other subdomain you enter gets redirected to original.
So www.anythinghere.site.com --redirects--> www.site.com

2 questions:

1. Specific code in htaccess that would redirect this URL (www.site.comwww.site.com) to the main site?
2. How can I find how this subdomain got created in the first place?

I've copied my htaccess so you can take a look ... I'm not the most technical person.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?  I think it is screwing around with my search rankings.

===================

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 #wpfx seo
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www..*

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]*).(com|com/)

  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in the the Webmaster Tools of Google and correct the url there. That should be the fastest way.

The redirect with 301 should be fine if you enable the mod rewrite in your `.htaccess` file. By the way you have to escape dots if you need them in a regex. Here are some improvments for your first three lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..*
```

Comment: the above code is the live htaccess file, so it is currently not redirecting the URL in question ...

Comment: @FXArt Please see my updates question. I could imagine that you maybe forgot to activate `ModRewrite` with the command `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment, this is just part of the htaccess code I have this up top                                                 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /